# Link Linked Lists in C

Tags: c, linked-list

I am trying to create an (ordered) linked list of (ordered) linked lists.  The list-of-list links are carried by the first nodes of its member lists.  I am trying to achieve this via the following code, but my program crashes right after I try to insert the second node into the list of lists.

Here's a schematic of the data structure I am trying to construct:
[image]

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>

struct node{
    int number;
    struct node*next;
    struct node*lsnext;
};

typedef struct node Node;
Node* insertValue(Node * list, int value);
void display(Node*);
Node* insertArr(Node * list, int value);

int main()
{

Node *globalList = NULL, *lists,*start,*save;
int nbrOfLists, listNo, nbrOfVal, valNo, val;

printf("\n Enter the number of lists:");
scanf("%d", &nbrOfLists);

if(nbrOfLists < 0)
    return -1;

for(listNo = 0; listNo < nbrOfLists; listNo++)
{
    printf("\n\n Enter the number of inputs to the list %d: \n ",listNo+1);
    scanf("%d", &nbrOfVal);
    lists = NULL;

    for(valNo = 0; valNo < nbrOfVal; valNo++)
    {
        printf("Enter node value %d:", valNo+1);
        scanf("%d", &val);
        // Here we insert the value in both lists
        lists= insertValue(lists, val);

        globalList = insertValue(globalList, val);
    }
      start=lists;
            if(listNo==0){
                save=start;
            }
            start=start->lsnext;

    printf("\n  The list %d is: ",listNo+1);
    display(lists);

}
printf("\n\n The final list is: ");
display(globalList);
printf("The first list is");
display(save);
printf("The second list is");
display(save->lsnext);  // CRASHES HERE 
return 0;
}

  Node* insertValue(Node * list, int value)
  {
  Node *newNode, *m;
  newNode = malloc(sizeof(Node));
  newNode->number=value;

 if(list == NULL)
 {
   newNode->next=NULL;
   return newNode;
 }

 if(value < list->number)
  {
   newNode->next = list;
   return newNode;
  }

 m = list;
 while(m->next)
 {
   if(value < m->next->number)
       break;
   m = m->next;
 }
 newNode->next = m->next;
 m->next = newNode;
 return list;
 }

 void display(Node*nodex){

    while(nodex)
    {
        printf("%d ->",nodex->number);
        nodex=nodex->next;
    }
}
```

What is causing my error?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't follow the circumstances under which you get an error: "right after I try insertion of first node into second list of first nodes of individual lists."  Would you please reword that more clearly?  When you do, please also describe exactly what error you get.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I am not being shown error but at runtime the program crashes right at the statement I have mentioned in the code. For better elaboration I would say that I am trying to add first node of second individual list by insertion in the end from lsnext pointer of the first node of first individual list.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I added a picture for better understanding.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through with a debugger?  What do you mean the program crashes?  Do you get a runtime error, perhaps a segmentation fault?

Answer (score 0):

Your `insertArr()` function is wrong.  Even its signature is wrong.  Instead of linking together the first nodes of existing lists, it creates a perpendicular list of separate nodes.  Note in particular that it accepts a *value* where it needs instead to accept the head node of a list.

Moreover, even the circumstances under which you call that function are wrong.  You seem to try to link the *initial* head nodes of each list, but the head node may change as you add values.  You must wait until you have a full list before you know what its final head node is; only then can you link that list into your list of lists.

**Edit**: I had first asserted that your problem was failure to initialize the `lsnext` members of your nodes.  That would be correct if your `insertArr()` function were actually accepting nodes created by `insertValue()` as its second argument, as it should, but it is not correct for the code presented. The actual problem is a consequence of the issue described in my first paragraph, that `insertArr()` creates a separate list *of separate nodes*.  In particular, those separate nodes do not have their `next` pointers initialized.